# Using Terraform Script have to get the credentials in Azure KeyVault like subscription id, client id, client secret

Tags: terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

I Am trying to deploy Azure storage account using terraform but i have stored my service credentials in Azure Keyvault it should pick the values from vault and deploy the  resources.below is script where im trying to achieve the same

> **Error**: unable to build authorizer for Resource Manager API: could not configure AzureCli Authorizer: could not parse Azure CLI version:
> launching Azure CLI: exec: "az": executable file not found in %PATH% │
> │   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"], │   on
> main.tf line 19, in provider "azurerm": │   19: provider "azurerm"

```
data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "client_id" {
  name         = "clientid"
  key_vault_id = "/subscriptions/id/resourceGroups/Cloud360-AzCred/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/AzCredentials"
}
data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "tenant_id" {
  name         = "tenantid"
  key_vault_id = "/subscriptions/id/resourceGroups/Cloud360-AzCred/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/AzCredentials"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "client_secret" {
  name         = "clientsecret"
  key_vault_id = "/subscriptions/id/resourceGroups/Cloud360-AzCred/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/AzCredentials"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "subscription_id" {
  name         = "subscriptionid"
  key_vault_id = "/subscriptions/id/resourceGroups/Cloud360-AzCred/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/AzCredentials"
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  skip_provider_registration = true
}
  locals{
    client_id       = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.client_id.value
    tenant_id        = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.tenant_id.value
    client_secret   = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.client_secret.value
    subscription_id = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.subscription_id.value
}
  
provider "azurerm" {
    alias           = "keyvault"
  client_id       = local.client_id
  tenant_id       = local.tenant_id
  client_secret   = local.client_secret
  subscription_id = local.subscription_id
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resourcesw"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "cndstorageacunt2023212"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to access CLI outside the Azure portal Follow [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) once you're done installing login using you're azure credentials.

Comment: Thanks for your response@Vinay B but iam not trying to access CLI i have provided the script above where am trying to achieve something different to access the credentials endup with that error assist me to resolve the issue..!

Comment: But from the error description, It is clear that you're trying to access the CLI where you're facing an authorization issue. Can you be more specific on that @User how and where are trying to access the Azure CLI from?

Comment: @Vinay B Im trying it from Visual studio code but im already providing the credentials to pick from keyvault but dont know im getting this error how to avoid that? My agenda here is to pick the cred from azure keyvault without hard coding in script and deploy the resources.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to use Terraform Script to get the credentials in Azure KeyVault like subscription ID, client ID, client secret, etc and I was able to achieve the requirement successfully.

The error suggests that Terraform tries to use Azure CLI for authentication but can't find the `az` command. This usually occurs when Azure CLI is not installed or not properly added to the system's PATH.

For [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) you can use this path to re-install the Azure CLI in your VSC.

Once you install try login into your Azure subscription using the command **`az login`**

[image]

Before going to the terraform steps make sure you define the correct path of your terraform in your environment variables.

Once we are done logging in, before running the terraform commands, ensure your user has the necessary permissions on the key vault and subscription level to avoid unnecessary blockers.

The necessary permission for the user should be **`secret reader`** and **`key vault administrator`**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**My terraform Configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                = "exkvvksb"
  resource_group_name = "demorg-vk"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "client_id" {
  name         = "clientid"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "tenant_id" {
  name         = "tenantid"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "client_secret" {
  name         = "clientsecret"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "subscription_id" {
  name         = "subscriptionid"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias           = "credentials"

  client_id       = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.client_id.value
  client_secret   = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.client_secret.value
  tenant_id       = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.tenant_id.value
  subscription_id = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.subscription_id.value

  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "storage_rg" {
  name     = "StorageRGvk"
  location = "east us"

  provider = azurerm.credentials
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "devkstoracc12"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.storage_rg.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.storage_rg.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  provider = azurerm.credentials
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]